# select rows after each row with if condition

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

First sorry for poor english !
two i have a table with many record >5000 with below structure

```
 id | uid | uam(user after me) | plan
-------------------------------------
 1  |  4  |        4           |  1
-------------------------------------
 2  |  4  |        3           |  2
-------------------------------------
 3  |  4  |        1           |  2
-------------------------------------
 4  |  4  |        9           |  1
-------------------------------------
 5  |  4  |        6           |  1
-------------------------------------
 6  |  4  |        2           |  2
-------------------------------------
 7  |  4  |        1           |  1
-------------------------------------
 8  |  4  |        3           |  2
-------------------------------------
```

now i want select from this table with below if/condition

select rows where uam ( user after me ) <= count rows after this row whit same plan . In other words, we want the users to have the same plan and the number of users after they have reached the number of uam.

for this example table should be return ids : 2, 3

how i can do it with sql or better with codeigniter active records?
thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each record you need to check if the subsequent records can sum up to a count greater than or equal to the `uam` of that particular record.

With the help of `EXISTS` you can achieve this:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM uamtable A 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 
  1
  FROM uamtable B 
  WHERE A.ID < B.ID AND A.plan = B.plan
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= A.uam
)
```

---

**Note:**

`A.ID < B.ID` constraint enforces that only the subsequent records will be counted having the same plan.

<kbd>[**SEE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71e3f/3/0)</kbd>

Comment: thanks and if i want add limit for pagination in this case where add limit?

Comment: Add an `order by A.ID` after `EXISTS` block.then add the limit like `LIMIT 1`